# R Studio doesn't load sjp.setThem function

Tags: sjplot

After re-installing sjPlot package I am not able to set a theme with sjp.setTheme. This is the message I get:

```
sjp.setTheme(theme = "scatter",
             geom.label.size = 3.5,
             geom.label.color = "white",
             axis.textsize = .8, 
             axis.title.size = .9)
```

Error in sjp.setTheme(theme = "scatter", geom.label.size = 3.5, geom.label.color = "white",  : 
  could not find function "sjp.setTheme"

Answer (score 0):

For the latest sjPlot-update, `sjp.setTheme()` has been renamed to `set_theme()`.